# Unseen Low Values and NULL in flat file

Tags: sql, ssis, flat-file

I have been sending a flat file to a vendor that is generated from an SQL query via SSIS.  The vendor is stating when they import the file into their mainframe NULL or low values are causing issues seeing invalid characters.  Has anyone ran into this before?  My query is below.  Do I need to replace "space" for non populated fields different?

```
--CREATE HEADER RECORD TABLE UH01
declare @uh01 table
( UH01 char(10),            --required field
 custcode char(9),        --required field
 processdatetime char(14),     --required field
 version char(4),          --required field
 filler char(475))         --required field

--Create table to store UA01 data


declare @ua01 table (
 recid int IDENTITY(1,1),
 UA01 char(10),                 --required field
 reporttype char(1),            --required field
 inscompanycode char(9),        --required field
 policynum char(30),            --required field
 policytype char(4),            --required field
 policyinceptiondate char(8),
 policyexpate char(8),
 policyrenewalind char(1),
 riskpolicyind char(1),
 claimno char(30),              --required field
 dateofloss char(8),            --required field
 timeofloss char(4),
 CatIndicator char(1),
 cat char(3),
 companyrecdate char(8),
 lossdesc char(50),
 loclossaddr1 char(50),
 loclossaddr2 char(50),
 loclosscity char(25),
 loclossst char(2),             --required field
 loclosspostal char(9),
 loclosscountry char(3),        --required field
 filler char(4),
 agencynotifiedofloss char(35),
 policefirereportnum char(15),
 routingmisinfo char(20),
 nosearchind char(1),
 datefirstclaimpayment char(8),
 fundclaim char(1),
 vesselcallnum char(50),
 apdfastcheckindicator char(1),
 legacyclaimconversionind char(1),
 requestclaimconversionind char(1),
 policereportinoccurenceind char(1),
 singlevehicleaccidentindicator char(1),
 phantomvehaccind char(1),
 wasaccwitnessed char(1),
 molddamage char(1),
 filler2 char(1),
 filler3 char(2),
 hitandrun char(1),
 reqrecallind char(1),
 masstortind char(1),       --required field
 selfinsuredind char(1),
 cobcassignedsectionID char(9),
 tin char(9),
 siteid char(9),
 nmvtisoprepid char(7),
 filler4 char(9),           --required field
 filler5 char(5))           --required field



 --CREATE UO01 TABLE PARTIES TO THE LOSS

 declare @uo01 table (
 recid int IDENTITY(1,1),
UO01 char(10),                  --required field
roleinclaim char(2),            --required field
individualbusinessind char(1),  --required field
businessname char(70),          --required field
lastname char(30),              --required field
firstname char(20),             --required field
middlename char(20),
dob char(8),
gender char(1),
ssn char(9),
tin char(9),
dln char(20),
dlstate char(2),
occupationrating char(50),
medproflicense char(15),
addr1 char(50),                 --required field
addr2 char(50),
city char(25),                  --required field
statecode char(2),              --required field
postalcode char(9),
countrycode char(3),
homephone char(10),
busphone char(10),
cellphone char(10),
pagernum char(10),
pagerpin char(7),
vehicreltoown char(2),
filler char(2),                 --required field
nosearchind char(1),
passportnum char(9),
routinginfo char(5),
vinofoccupant char(20),
datereportedloss char(8),
faxnum char(10),
searchchildsupportind char(1),
filler1 char(1),                --required field
filler2 char(70))               --required field




declare @uc01 table
(
 recid int IDENTITY(1,1),
UC01 char(10),                  --required field
filler char(9),
adjnamelast char(30),
adjnamefirst char(20),
adjnamemid char(20),
adjphone char(10),
losstype char(4),               --required field
coveragetype char(4),           --required field
injurysdamage char(50),         --required field
bodypart char(2),
filler1 char(3),                --required field
claimstatus char(3),
tortthresholdtype char(2),
tortthresholdstate char(2),
suitindicator char(1),
estlossamt char(11),
reserveamt char(11),
settlementamt char(11),
dateclaimclosed char(8),
routingmiscinfo char(20),
losstimestartdate char(8),
losstimeenddate char(8),
totallostdays char(5),
courtfiledtype char(10),
courtfileddate char(8),
physicaldamage char(1),
icd9code char(6),
icd9code1 char(6),
icd9code2 char(6),
icd9code3 char(6),
icd9code4 char(6),
deathresultofinjury char(1),
dateattorneyinvolv char(8),
noticedateemployer char(8),
cptcode char(5),
benefittypecode char(3),
employmentstatcode char(2), 
dateofretirement char(8),
dateofstrike char(8),
preexistingdiscode char(2),
personinsattimeofloss char(1),
empdateofhire char(8),
datetermlaid char(8),
ambulance char(1),
disabled char(1),
pdmedbills char(11),
pdindemnity char(11),
totalpaid char(11),
courtcounty char(25),
courtstate char(2),
docketnum char(25),
adjustemailadd char(50),
erisaclaim char(1),
filler2 char(15))               --required field

--Populate UH01
--POPULATE THE HEADER RECORD TABLE UH01
insert into @uh01
select '000000UH01', + --filetype
'S73200001', + --custcode
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), CONVERT(DATETIME, getdate(), 112), 126), '-', ''), 'T', ''), ':', ''), --processdatetime
'US01',   --version
space(475) --filler


 --POPULATE THE UA01 table
insert into @ua01
select 
--ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
'000000UA01', --UA01
'I', --reporttype
'S73200001', --inscompanycode
isnull(rtrim(convert(char(30), po.policyid)), space(30)), --policynum
'PAPP', --policytype
isnull(left(convert(char(8), po.inceptdt, 112), 8), space(8)), --policyinceptiondate
isnull(left(convert(char(8), po.expiratdt, 112), 8), space(8)), --policyexpate
space(1), --policyrenewalind
space(1), --riskpolicyind
isnull(convert(char(30), c1.agencynumb), space(30)), --Claim Number
isnull(left(convert(char(8), c.doi, 112), 8), space(8)), --dateofloss
isnull(left(convert(char(4), c.accdtime, 114), 4), space(4)), --timeofloss
space(1), --CatIndicator
space(3), --cat@
isnull(left(convert(char(8), c.lworkdate, 112), 8), space(8)), --companyrecdate
space(50), --lossdesc
space(50), --loclossaddr1 
space(50), --loclossaddr2
space(25), --loclosscity
convert(char(2),c1.jurst), --loclossst
space(9), --loclosspostal
'USA', --loclosscountry
space(4), --filler
space(35), --agencynotifiedofloss
space(15), --policefirereportnum
space(20), --routingmisinfo
space(1), --nosearchind
space(8), --datefirstclaimpayment
space(1), --fundclaim
space(50), --vesselcallnum
space(1), --apdfastcheckindicator
space(1), --legacyclaimconversionind
space(1), --requestclaimconversionind
space(1), --policereportinoccurenceind
space(1), --singlevehicleaccidentindicator
space(1), --phantomvehaccind
space(1), --wasaccwitnessed
space(1), --molddamage
space(1), --filler2
space(2), --filler3
space(1), --hitandrun
space(1), --reqrecallind
space(1), --masstortind 
case
 when ca.invmsg like 'SELF%' then 'Y' 
 else 'N'
 end,       --selfinsuredind
space(9),  --cobcassignedsectionID
space(9),   --tin
space(9),   --siteid
space(7),   --nmvtisoprepid
space(9),   --filler4
space(5)    --filler5

from claim c
join v_initial_bi v on c.claimno = v.claimno
join claim1 c1 on c.claimno = c1.lnkclaimno
join claim2 c2 on c.claimno = c2.link2claim
join person p on c.patient = p.personid
join cmpolicy cm on c.claimno = cm.claimno
join policy po on cm.policyid = po.policyid
join carrier ca on c.carrier = ca.code
where  cast (v.INITBI as date) = cast (getdate()-1 as date) 

--POPULATE THE WC CLAIM DETAIL TABLE UO01
insert into @uo01
select
--ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
'000000UO01', --UO01
'CL', --roleinclaim
'B', --individualbusinessind
isnull(rtrim(convert(char(70), ph.name)), space(70)), --businessname
isnull(rtrim(convert(char(30), p.lname)), space(30)),  --lastname
isnull(rtrim(convert(char(20), p.fname)), space(20)),  --firstname
isnull(rtrim(convert(char(20), p.mname)), space(20)),  --middlename
space(8), --dob
case
  when p.sex = 1 then 'M'
  when p.sex = 2 then 'F'
  else ' '
 end,
space(9), --SSN
space(9), --tin
space(20), --dln
space(2), --dlstate
space(50), --occupationrating
space(15), --medproflicense
isnull(rtrim(convert(char(50), p.addr1)), space(50)), --Addr1
isnull(rtrim(convert(char(50), p.addr2)), space(50)), --Addr2
isnull(rtrim(convert(char(25), p.city)), space(25)), --Employee City
isnull(rtrim(convert(char(2), p.state)), space(2)), --Employee State
isnull(rtrim(convert(char(9), p.zip)), space(9)), --Employee Zip
space(3), --countrycode
isnull(rtrim(convert(char(10), p.phone)), space(10)), --Employee phone
space(10), --busphone
space(10), --cellphone
space(10), --pagernum
space(7), --pagerpin
space(2), --vehicreltoown
space(2), --filler 
space(1), --nosearchind
space(9), --passportnum
space(5), --routinginfo
space(20),   --vinofoccupant
space(8),   --datereportedloss
space(10),   --faxnum
space(1),   --searchchildsupportind
space(1), --filler1
space(70) --filer2


from claim c
join v_initial_bi v on c.claimno = v.claimno
join claim1 c1 on c.claimno = c1.lnkclaimno
join claim2 c2 on c.claimno = c2.link2claim
join person p on c.patient = p.personid
join cmpolicy cm on c.claimno = cm.claimno
join policy po on cm.policyid = po.policyid
join carrier ca on c.carrier = ca.code
join masttype m on c.casetype = m.mastid
left join employer e on c.empcode = e.code
left join employer ph on e.polholder = ph.code
left join dictdata d7 on c2.losstype = d7.datumid       --Type Of Loss Code 
where  cast (v.INITBI as date) = cast (getdate()-1 as date) 

 --POPULATE THE UC01 TABLE PARTIES TO THE LOSS
insert into @uc01
select 
--ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
'000000UC01', --UC01
space(9), --filler
space(30), --adjnamelast
space(20), --adjnamefirst
space(20), --adjnamemid
space(10), --adjphone
isnull(convert(char(4), d7.code), '0001'), --losstype
left(m.mastdesc, 4),--coveragetype
isnull(rtrim(convert(char(50), c.accdesc)), space(50)), --injurysdamage
space(2), --bodypart
space(3), --filler
convert(char(3), c.status), --Claim Status 
space(2), --tortthresholdtype
space(2),--tortthresholdstate
space(1), --suitindicator
space(11), --estlossamt
space(11), --reserveamt
space(11), --settlementamt
space(8), --dateclaimclosed
space(20), --routingmiscinfo
space(8),  --losstimestartdate
space(8),  --losstimeenddate
space(5), --totallostdays
space(10),  --courtfiledtype
space(8),  --courtfileddate
space(1), --physicaldamage
space(6), --icd9code
space(6), --icd9code1
space(6), --icd9code2
space(6), --icd9code3
space(6), --icd9code4
space(1), --deathresultofinjury
space(8),  --dateattorneyinvolv
space(8), --noticedateemployer
space(5), --cptcode
space(3), --benefittypecode
space(2), --employmentstatcode
space(8), --dateofretirement
space(8), --dateofstrike
space(2), --preexistingdiscode
space(1), --personinsattimeofloss
space(8), --empdateofhire
space(8), --datetermlaid
space(1), --ambulance
space(1), --disabled
space(11), --pdmedbills
space(11), --pdindemnity
space(11), --totalpaid
space(25), --courtcounty
space(2),    --courtstate
space(25),  --docketnum
space(50),   --adjustemailadd
space(1),  --erisaclaim 
space(15) --filler2

from claim c
join v_initial_bi v on c.claimno = v.claimno
join claim1 c1 on c.claimno = c1.lnkclaimno
join claim2 c2 on c.claimno = c2.link2claim
join person p on c.patient = p.personid
join cmpolicy cm on c.claimno = cm.claimno
join policy po on cm.policyid = po.policyid
join carrier ca on c.carrier = ca.code
join masttype m on c.casetype = m.mastid
left join employer e on c.empcode = e.code
left join employer ph on e.polholder = ph.code
left join dictdata d7 on c2.losstype = d7.datumid       --Type Of Loss Code 
---where INITBI = GETDATE() //TO UNCOMMENT, COMMENTED FOR TESTING ONLY
where  cast (v.INITBI as date) = cast (getdate()-1 as date) 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
declare @outputtable table
(
id int identity(1,1),
recid int,
rectype varchar(10),
result varchar(max)
)

declare @TotalCount int
declare @ProcessedCount int = 2
declare @LastProcessedType varchar(10) = 'X'
declare @uocount int = 0;
declare @seqcode varchar(10)
set @TotalCount = ( (select count(1)  from @uc01) + (select count(1) from @ua01) + (select count(1)  from @uo01))
print @TotalCount


--Declare and populate UZ01 segment. 

declare @uz01 table
(UZ01 char(10),                 --required field
totalrectrans char(6),          --required field
filler char(480))               --required field

--INSERT HEADER RECORD

INSERT INTO @outputtable  
SELECT
0,
'HEADER',

'000001UH01' + --filetype
'S73200001' + --custcode
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), CONVERT(DATETIME, getdate(), 112), 126), '-', ''), 'T', ''), ':', '')+ --processdatetime
'US01' +   --version
space(475) --filler





--UA, UO, UO, UC
WHILE( (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @outputtable) < @TotalCount)
BEGIN


    --INITIAL ATTEMPT AND UA 
    IF (@LastProcessedType = 'X' OR @LastProcessedType = 'UA')
    BEGIN
        print 'UA'

        set @seqcode = (concat ( REPLICATE('0', 10-LEN( concat(@ProcessedCount, 'UA01'))), concat(@ProcessedCount, 'UA01')))
        INSERT INTO @outputtable
            SELECT 
            top 1
            ua.recid, 'UA', 

                        ----
                        @seqcode+
                        rtrim(reporttype) + space(1 - len(reporttype)) + --reporttype
                        rtrim(inscompanycode) + space(9 - len(inscompanycode)) + --inscompanycode
                        rtrim(policynum) + space(30 -len(policynum)) + --Claimant number
                        rtrim(policytype) + space(4 -len(policytype)) +  --policytype   --required field
                        space(8) + --policyinceptiondate 
                        space(8) + --policyexpate 
                        space(1) + --policyrenewalind
                        space(1) + --riskpolicyind
                        rtrim(claimno) + space(30 - len(claimno)) +         --required field
                        rtrim(dateofloss) + space(8 - len(dateofloss)) +        --required field
                        space(4) + --timeofloss
                        space(1) + --CatIndicator
                        space(3) + --cat@
                        space(8) +  --companyrecdate 
                        space(50) + --lossdesc
                        space(50) + --loclossaddr1
                        space(50) + --loclossaddr2
                        space(25) + --loclosscity 
                        rtrim(loclossst + space(2 -len(loclossst)) +        --required field
                        space(9) + --loclosspostal 
                        'USA' +     --required field
                        space(4) +  --Filler
                        space(35) + --agencynotifiedofloss
                        space(15) + --policefirereportnum 
                        space(20) + --routingmisinfo 
                        space(1) + --nosearchind 
                        space(8) + --datefirstclaimpayment
                        space(1) + --fundclaim 
                        space(50) + --vesselcallnum 
                        space(1) + --apdfastcheckindicator
                        space(1) + --legacyclaimconversionind
                        space(1) + --requestclaimconversionind 
                        space(1) + --policereportinoccurenceind 
                        space(1) + --singlevehicleaccidentindicator
                        space(1) + --phantomvehaccind 
                        space(1) + --wasaccwitnessed 
                        space(1) + --molddamage 
                        space(1) + --filler2 
                        space(2) +  --filler3 
                        space(1) +  --hitandrun
                        space(1) + --reqrecallind
                        space(1) + --masstortind
                        selfinsuredind) + space(1 -len(selfinsuredind)) +  --selfinsuredind 
                        space(9) +  --cobcassignedsectionID
                        space(9) + --tin 
                        space(9) +  --siteid 
                        space(7) +  --nmvtisoprepid 
                        space(9) +   --filler4          --required field
                        space(5)    --filler5           --required field

                        --



            FROM @ua01 ua
            WHERE  ua.recid NOT IN
                (
                    select recid from @outputtable where rectype = 'UA'
                )

         SET @ProcessedCount = @ProcessedCount+1
         SET @LastProcessedType = 'UO'
    END

    IF (@LastProcessedType = 'UO')
    BEGIN
        print 'UO'
        set @seqcode = (concat ( REPLICATE('0', 10-LEN( concat(@ProcessedCount, 'UO01'))), concat(@ProcessedCount, 'UO01')))
        INSERT INTO @outputtable
            SELECT
            top 1
             uo.recid, 'UO', 

                                     ----------------------
                    @seqcode +  --Record indicator 
                    'CL' + --roleinclaim            
                    'B' + --individualbusinessind  
                    rtrim(businessname) + space(70 - len(businessname)) + -- business name --required field
                    rtrim(lastname) + space(30 -  len(lastname)) + --Last name --required field
                    rtrim(firstname) + space (20 - len(firstname)) +    --Firstname --required field
                    rtrim(middlename) + space (20 - len(middlename)) +  --middle name --required field
                    rtrim(dob) + space (8 - len(dob)) +    --required field
                    rtrim(gender) + space (1 - len(gender)) +  --required field
                    rtrim(ssn) + space (9 - len(ssn)) + --gender
                    space(9) + --tin tax id num
                    space(20) + --drivers license number
                    space(2) + --driver license state
                    space(50) + --occupationrating 
                    space(15) + --medproflicense 
                    rtrim(addr1) + space (50 - len(addr1)) +                    --required field
                    rtrim(addr2) + space (50 - len(addr2)) +  
                    rtrim(city) + space  (25 - len(city)) +                 --required field
                    rtrim(statecode) + space (2 - len(statecode)) +             --required field
                    rtrim(postalcode) + space (9 - len(postalcode)) + --postalcode 
                    space(3) + --spacecountrycode 
                    space(10) + --homephone 
                    space(10) + --busphone 
                    space(10) + --cellphone
                    space(10) + --pagernum 
                    space(7) + --pagerpin 
                    space(2) + --vehicreltoown
                    space(2) + --filler
                    space(1) + --nosearchind
                    space(9) + --passportnum 
                    space(5) + --routinginfo 
                    space(20) + --vinofoccupant 
                    space(8) + --datereportedloss 
                    space(10) + --faxnum 
                    space(1) + --searchchildsupportind 
                    space(1) + --filler1 
                    space(70)  --filler2 

             ----------------------

            FROM @uo01 uo
            WHERE  uo.recid NOT IN
                (
                    select recid from @outputtable where rectype = 'UO'
                )

        SET @ProcessedCount = @ProcessedCount+1
        SET @LastProcessedType = 'UC'







    IF (@LastProcessedType = 'UC')
    BEGIN
            print 'UC'
            set @seqcode = (concat ( REPLICATE('0', 10-LEN( concat(@ProcessedCount, 'UC01'))), concat(@ProcessedCount, 'UC01')))
            INSERT INTO @outputtable
            SELECT top 1
            uc.recid, 'UC',

                ------------------------
                @seqcode +  --Record indicator 
                space(9) + --filler   --required field
                space(30) + --adjnamelast
                space(20) + --adjnamefirst
                space(20) + --adjnamemid 
                space(10) +  --adjphone
                rtrim(losstype) + space(4 - len(losstype)) + --losstype --required field
                rtrim(coveragetype) + space(4 -len(coveragetype)) + --coveragetype
                rtrim(injurysdamage) + space(50 - len(injurysdamage)) + --injurysdamage --required field
                space(2) + --bodypart
                space(3) +  --filler1               --required field
                space(3) +  --claimstatus
                space(2) +  --tortthresholdtype 
                space(2) +  --tortthresholdstate 
                space(1) + --suitindicator 
                space(11) + --estlossamt 
                space(11) + --reserveamt 
                space(11) +  --settlementamt 
                space(8) + --dateclaimclosed 
                space(20) + --routingmiscinfo
                space(8) +  --losstimestartdate
                space(8) +  --losstimeenddate 
                space(5) +  --totallostdays
                space(10) +  --courtfiledtype 
                space(8) +   --courtfileddate
                space(1) +  --physicaldamage 
                space(6) +   --icd9code 
                space(6) +   --icd9code1 
                space(6) +   --icd9code2 
                space(6) +   --icd9code3 
                space(6) +  --icd9code4 
                space(1) +   --deathresultofinjury 
                space(8) +  --dateattorneyinvolv 
                space(8) +  --noticedateemployer 
                space(5) + --cptcode char
                space(3) + --benefittypecode 
                space(2) + --employmentstatcode 
                space(8) + --dateofretirement 
                space(8) + --dateofstrike 
                space(2) + --preexistingdiscode
                space(1) + --personinsattimeofloss 
                space(8) + --empdateofhire 
                space(8) + --datetermlaid
                space(1) + --ambulance 
                space(1) + --disabled 
                space(11) + --pdmedbills 
                space(11) + --pdindemnity 
                space(11) + --totalpaid 
                space(25) + --courtcounty 
                space(2) + --courtstate
                space(25) + --docketnum 
                space(50) + --adjustemailadd 
                space(1) + --erisaclaim 
                space(15)  --filler2    


------------------------------
            FROM @uc01 uc
            WHERE  uc.recid NOT IN
                (
                    select recid from @outputtable where rectype = 'UC'
                )

         SET @LastProcessedType = 'UA'
         SET @ProcessedCount = @ProcessedCount+1

    END



    END

END


INSERT INTO @outputtable
SELECT
0,
'TRAILER',
concat('0000', @ProcessedCount , 'UZ01' , '0000', @ProcessedCount)

--left(space(6 - len(convert(varchar, count(*)))) + convert(varchar, count(*)), 6) from @outputtable

--select '0000'+ @ProcessedCount + 'UZ01' + '10000'+ @ProcessedCount
--000042UZ01000042

select result from @outputtable order by id
```

Comment: uploading files to a mainframe can be a little tricky. i guess it is an IBM mainframe? i am pretty sure it is something about encodings. maybe when converting to EBCDIC.

Comment: I do believe it is an IBM mainframe.  Unsure of the OS.

Comment: which format is your output file? UTF-8? ANSI?
This is where i would start do search and discuss with them. As i understood, they're the mainframe experts, so they should know ;-) Do you by purpose know how the file uploaded to the mainframe?

Comment: My file is ANSI.  The vendor is unable to provide with a required format of the file other than "flat".  They are even unable to tell me how to send it (Binary, plain text, etc) other than with a "put" command.

Comment: you have to talk to the "upload program" owner of your vendor to discuss compatibility of data from source (yours) to destination (mainframe/theirs)

Comment: as @FerdinandGaspar said, you have to talk to them about the format. in my experience a CSV file is a very common way. but uploading to mainframe is a very special task. just mainframe experienced people know how to do this task (and not even all of them) ;-)